# Calculate the no of days between current year and given year in ios

Tags: ios

I have Listed Birthday List in Current month order(August,September....July)

I have calculated the no of days between current date and Birthday List date.

In ViewDidLoad method

```
NSDateFormatter *curdatemonthnoformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [curdatemonthnoformatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [curdatemonthnoformatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM"];
    NSString * curdatemonthnostring = [curdatemonthnoformatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    [curdatemonthnoformatter release];


    NSDateFormatter *tempFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [tempFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM"];
    NSDate *startdate = [tempFormatter dateFromString:curdatemonthnostring];
    NSLog(@"%@",startdate);
    [tempFormatter release];


    NSLog(@"%@",curdatemonthnostring);

    for (int val=0; val<[monthlistArray count]; val++)
    {
        NSMutableArray * dataarraylocal = [[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:0]autorelease];

        for (int ival=0; ival<[[monthdataArray objectAtIndex:val]count]; ival++)

        {
            NSString *birthdatestr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[monthdataArray objectAtIndex:val]objectAtIndex:ival]objectForKey:@"birthday"]];

            NSDate *mybirthdate=[formatter dateFromString:birthdatestr];
            NSDateFormatter *birthdatemonthFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [birthdatemonthFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
            [birthdatemonthFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM"];
            NSString *sortmonthstr = [birthdatemonthFormatter stringFromDate:mybirthdate];

            NSDateFormatter *tempFormatter1 = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
            [tempFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"dd-MM"];
            NSDate *toDate = [tempFormatter1 dateFromString:sortmonthstr];
            [dataarraylocal addObject:toDate];

        }
        [previouscomparearray addObject:dataarraylocal];
    }


    NSLog(@"%@",previouscomparearray);

    for (int ival=0; ival<[monthlistArray count]; ival++)
    {
        NSMutableArray *nofdayslocal=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:0];
        for (int jval=0; jval<[[monthdataArray objectAtIndex:ival]count]; jval++)
        {
            unsigned flags = NSDayCalendarUnit;
            NSDateComponents *difference = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:flags fromDate:startdate toDate:[[previouscomparearray objectAtIndex:ival]objectAtIndex:jval] options:0];

            int dayDiff = [difference day];

            NSLog(@"%d",dayDiff);

            [nofdayslocal addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:dayDiff]];

        }

        [comparedatearray addObjectsFromArray:nofdayslocal];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",comparedatearray);
```

Output:

```
"-8",
"-5",
"-1",
31,
83,
115,
"-220",
"-154",
"-154",
"-130",
"-90",
"-80",
"-73",
"-68",
"-63",
"-44",
"-42"
```

It calculated within current year.I want after December its will be calculate based on Next Year.

Any Idea Please help me.

Comment: Please look into the [SO Disscusion][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584286/number-of-day-of-current-year-in-ios

Answer (score 0):

You can find a whole guide for Date and Time Programming. Here is a link(https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007836-SW1) which gives you help on what to do.

```
NSString *first = @"2010-10-09";
NSString *second = @"2011-12-10";

NSDateFormatter *form = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[form setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSDate *startDate = [form dateFromString:first];
NSDate *endDate = [form dateFromString:second];

NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *comp = [gregorianCalendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                                fromDate:startDate
                                                  toDate:endDate
                                                 options:0];
```

comp will have the difference in the number of days. You can print and check. Good luck. :)

Comment: add   
int numberOfdays=[comp day]; at the end to get number of days in between two dates.

Comment: not worked.Prints the same result.