# Calculate the no of days based on year in ios

Tags: ios, nsdate

I will calculate the no of days based on Years.For Ex:If this month is September,then calculate the no of days (September...December) based on Current year.And After Jan,It will be calculate based next year.

I retrieve the no of months from Current month upto end of month.

```
NSDate *curmonth=[NSDate date];
NSString *endmonthstr=@"2013-12-31";

NSDateFormatter *endmonthformatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[endmonthformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *endmonth=[endmonthformatter dateFromString:endmonthstr];

NSInteger month = [[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSMonthCalendarUnit
                                                   fromDate: curmonth
                                                     toDate: endmonth
                                                    options: 0] month];

NSInteger monthplus=month+1;
NSInteger count=monthplus;

NSLog(@"%d",monthplus);
```

But,I dont know how to compare this and calculate the days.

Any idea please help me

Comment: Compare? Why don't you get the days from `components:fromDate:...`?

Comment: Instead of `NSMonthCalendarUnit` use `NSMonthCalendarUnit| NSDaysCalendarUnit`

Comment: It displays the negative values wain

Comment: Hai Main, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18479616/calculate-the-no-of-days-between-current-year-and-given-year-in-ios.Refer this link,same problem occured looks like

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of days remaining in the current year, you can use `NSCalendar` to find the difference in date components for you. You can specify different components, but since you want the days, just use `NSDayCalendarUnit`.

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

// GET CURRENT YEAR / MONTH / DAY
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *nowComps = [cal components: NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate: now];

// COPY TODAY'S COMPONENTS, BUT CHANGE MONTH AND DAY
NSDateComponents *lastDayComps = [nowComps copy];
lastDayComps.month = 12;
lastDayComps.day = 31;

// GENERATE LAST DAY FROM COMPONENTS
NSDate *lastDay = [cal dateFromComponents: lastDayComps];

// CALCULATE DAYS BETWEEN DATES
NSDateComponents *components = [cal components: NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate: now toDate: lastDay options: 0];
NSInteger daysTilEndOfYear = components.day;
```

Comment: Its displays dateWithNaturalLanguageString method is not found